# yfinance AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'

Tags: python, pandas

При попытке запуска кода с тикером 'tsla' или например 'msft' выдает ошибку AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'. Но с тикером 'aapl' работает корректно.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')

ticker2 = 'tsla'
ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker2)

stock_info = ticker.info

def a1():
    global ticker
    global stock_info
    a_y = ticker.earnings
    a = pd.DataFrame(a_y)
    y1 = a.iloc[0]['Earnings']
    y2 = a.iloc[1]['Earnings']
    y3 = a.iloc[2]['Earnings']
    y4 = a.iloc[3]['Earnings']
    y2pr = ((y2-y1)/y1)*100
    y3pr = ((y3-y2)/y2) * 100
    y4pr = ((y4-y3)/y3) * 100

    p = yf.download(ticker2, interval='1d', start='2017-12-31', end='2022-01-04', rounding = 
True)['Adj Close']
    p = pd.DataFrame(p)

    yc1 = p.loc['2019-01-02']['Adj Close']
    yc2 = p.loc['2020-01-02']['Adj Close']
    yc3 = p.loc['2021-01-04']['Adj Close']
    yc4 = p.loc['2022-01-03']['Adj Close']
    yc2pr = ((yc2 - yc1) / yc1) * 100
    yc3pr = ((yc3 - yc2) / yc2) * 100
    yc4pr = ((yc4 - yc3) / yc3) * 100

    print('Изменение цены акции от 2019 к 2020: ' + str(yc2pr.round(2)) + '%\n' +
          'Изменение цены акции от 2020 к 2021: ' + str(yc3pr.round(2)) + '%\n' +
          'Изменение цены акции от 2021 к 2022: ' + str(yc4pr.round(2)) + '%\n')

    print('Изменение прибыли от 2018 к 2019: ' + str(y2pr.round(2)) + '%\n' +
          'Изменение прибыли от 2019 к 2020: ' + str(y3pr.round(2)) + '%\n' +
          'Изменение прибыли от 2020 к 2021: ' + str(y4pr.round(2)) + '%\n')

    if y2pr or y3pr or y4pr < 25:
        print('Компания не удовлетворяет условиям')

    elif yc2pr or yc3pr or yc4pr < 17:
        print('Компания не удовлетворяет условиям')

    else:
        print('Компания удовлетворяет условиям, посмотрите институциональных инвесторов компании, \n' +
              ' а также проверьте является ли компания лидером своей отрасли и насколько она ликвидна, \n' +
              ' , если же она удовлетворяет всем условиям то можете её купить')

        holders = stock_info.major_holders
        iholders = stock_info.institusional_holders

        print(holders)
        print(iholders)

a1()
```

(заранее извиняюсь за читаемость кода)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка исчезла после того, как я сменил версию pandas с 1.4.0 на 1.3.5